# Find node in Document

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

I have obtained a node through `document.getSelection().anchorNode` and I would like to view it as an element as though it were fetched by a query selector.
Say my node is a `p` element containing the string `hello world`

```
<p>hello world</p>
```

The node appears in the DOM here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/master.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I woudl like to get the `<p>` element from the document. But, a node that looks the same can appear several times, I would like to get the HTML element this node comes from.

Thanks

Comment: Whwt do you mean by *"I would like to view it as an element as though it were fetched by a query selector"*? If the node is the `p` element in your example, it's exactly the same object you'd get from `querySelector`.

Comment: `document.getSelection().anchorNode instanceof HTMLElement === false`

Comment: Then it **isn't** the `p` element. It's probably a Text node within it.

Comment: then why does the parent node's prototype not match that of a HTMLElement?

Comment: what have you done??? it's working!

Answer (score 1):

> Say my node is a `p` element containing the string hello world

Then `anchorNode` will be **exactly** the same object you'd get from `querySelector`.

But if it's the Text node *within* that `p` element, you'd want to use `anchorNode.parentElement` to access the `p` element.

Live Example:

```js
var lastNode = null;
setInterval(function() {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var node = (selection && selection.anchorNode) || null;
  if (node === lastNode) {
    return;
  }
  lastNode = node;
  if (!node) {
    console.log("(No selection)");
  } else {
    var result = "Node name is " + node.nodeName;
    if (node.nodeType === 3) { // Text
      console.log(result, "parent element:", node.parentElement);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
}, 250);
```

```html
Select some text, an analysis of <code>window.getSelection().anchorNode</code>'s result will appear in the console.
<p>hello world</p>
```